# Exclude rows with missing values in several columns

Tags: r, for-loop, na

I have a dataset consisting of >200 columns and >3000 rows. Some of them is NA in  specific columns, and i want to exclude these individuals preferable with a for loop.

In the cases where the row is NA in all 18 columns I want to exclude these from the entire dataframe. The names of the 18 variables is: "q_81_SQ00a", "q_81_SQ00b", "q_81_SQ00c" (...) "q_81_SQ00r". As you can see all variables have the same name but with a different last letter (except for q which is missing).

I've tried this with no success:

```
lapply(letters[c(1:16,18)], function(x){

  df <- na.omit(data.family[[paste0("q_81_SQ00", x)]])
})
```

With this code I just get a list of all rownumbers. It should be said that I'm using the for loop with succes when calculating significance with Fisher test, e.g.:

```
lapply(letters[c(1:16,18)], function(x){

  fisher.test(data.family$related,
                          data.family[[paste0("q_81_SQ00", x)]])
  })
```

Comment: `v <- apply(data.family, 2, function(x) mean(is.na(x))` will give you the mean of `na`present for each column (individual). If you want to delete the individuals with all values `na` just delete the columns for wich `v ==1`

Comment: Correct me if i don't understand this correctly - but this code will return a vector for each column seperately. I would like to know which rows is NA in all 18 columns, and after that i want to exclude these rows.

Comment: @JulieRavn Yes, with Margin =  2, apply will run a function over the columns. The solution that I provided with Margin=1 will loop over the rows and count the number of na's.

Comment: @JulieRavn so, just select `which(v ==1)` to the previous code, and it will give you the columns with all missing values.

Answer (score 1):

The apply function is used to apply a function over a column or row (depending on value of Margin =1 (row), Margin = 2(column)) of a matrix or matrix like data structure.

na_count is the count of na's in each row of data.family
then subset data.family excluding rows where all columns were NA's by checking for na_count==18.

```
na_count<-apply(X = data.family,MARGIN = 1,function(t){length(which(is.na(t)))})
data.family<-data.family[-which(na_count==18),]
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer may end up in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: @Jens Explained it.